# Prove that $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1^6+x_2^5+x_3^4=0\}$ is not manifold.

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Prove that $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1^6+x_2^5+x_3^4=0\}$ is not smooth manifold.

Of course, only $(0,0,0)$ is problemtic. I suppose we need to show that around $(0,0,0)$, we cannot present one variable as inversible function of two other variables, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course only $(0,0,0)$ is problematic. If given set is smooth manifold, then we can find function which is $C^1$ and near $(0,0,0)$ set is graph of this function. We can easily find suspectible functions:
$x_1=\pm(-x_2^5-x_3^4)^{1/6}$, $x_2=(-x_1^6-x_3^4)^{1/5}$ and $x_3=\pm(-x_1^6-x_2^5)^{1/4}$

First and third equations are not equations of functions, because they do not have univocal solutions. Second one is equation of function $x_2(x_1,x_3)$, but it does not have partial derivatives in $(0,0,0)$, therefore it is not $C^1$. From that follows that our set is not smooth manifold.

Answer (score 0):

Our set is defined as the zeros of a polynomial $F(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. A regular point is such that $\left(F_{x_1},F_{x_2},F_{x_3}\right)\neq (0,0,0)$. It is straightforward that $(0,0,0)$ is a singular point.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez Álvarez the only point in $\Bbb{R}^2$ that verifies $x^2-y^4=0$, $2x=0$ and $4y^3=0$ is $(0,0)$, unless I missed something

Comment: Yup my example does not work — I have no yet had my coffee. But that the gradient be nonzero is a sufficient condition for smoothness, not necessary.

Comment: Except in the case of polynomial i.e algebraic varieties

Comment: Well, my point is that the OP does not probably know that.

Comment: Yeah, I do not.

Comment: Let me then turn into a less algebraic proof

Comment: Having singular points doesn't exclude the object from being a smooth manifold at all. $\bigl\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ (x^2+y^2-1)^2=0\bigr\}$ has lots of singular points, yet it's a smooth manifold.